Swift C++ interop class with destructor
How do I create a C++ class that Swift can interop with that has a destructor? For example:
// C++
namespace Name {
    class Foo
    {
    public:
        Foo() = default;
        Foo(uint32_t i); // implemented in .cpp file
        ~Foo(); // implemented in .cpp file
    };
}

// Swift
import cxxLib
let bar = Name.Foo(2)

Writing this code gives me an error:
main.swift: error: 'Foo' is unavailable: non-trivial C++ class with trivial ABI is not yet available in Swift
let bar = Name.Foo(2)
               ^~~
__ObjC.cv:3:19: note: 'Foo' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
    public struct Foo {
                  ^

When I remove the destructor, the code works fine. Classes in the C++ standard library can be used if a type alias is created for the template, and these class must have destructors to free memory, so how can I acheive this?
I am using windows, swift version 5.10

From the documentation: "if the C++ type has a destructor, Swift will call the destructor when a Swift value of such type is destroyed". So at least in principle classes with destructor are supposed to be supported.
